# Getting Nan while using floating point number but runs well using integers number in python programing

Tags: python, nan

I am working on a python program where if I use floating point number I get Nan but if I use integers my program runs and I get a value other than Nan. I am not able to find the reason behind it and how to rectify it. Please help.

Below is my program where I have used values 11 and 10.3 in den_0 and also the output obtained by each of the values in the program

Input

```
lst_2=[]
newlst=[1]
prod=1
for k in range (1,25):
    for j in range (1,k+1):
        den_0=11+(j-1)*2 
        prod=den_0*prod
    lst_2.append(prod) 
newlst.extend(lst_2) 
newlst.pop(-1)      
den=list(map(truediv,lst_2,newlst))
```

Output

```
[11.0,
 143.0,
 2145.0,
 36465.0,
 692835.0,
 14549535.0,
 334639305.0,
 8365982625.0,
 225881530875.0,
 6550564395375.0,
 203067496256625.0,
 6701227376468625.0,
 2.345429581764019e+17,
 8.67808945252687e+18,
 3.384454886485479e+20,
 1.3876265034590464e+22,
 5.9667939648739e+23,
 2.685057284193255e+25,
 1.2619769235708297e+27,
 6.183686925497066e+28,
 3.1536803320035035e+30,
 1.671450575961857e+32,
 9.192978167790213e+33,
 5.239997555640421e+35]
```

Input

```
lst_2=[]
newlst=[1]
prod=1
for k in range (1,25):
    for j in range (1,k+1):
        den_0=10.3+(j-1)*2 
        prod=den_0*prod
    lst_2.append(prod) 
newlst.extend(lst_2) 
newlst.pop(-1)       
den=list(map(truediv,lst_2,newlst))
```

Output

```
[10.3,
 126.69000000000003,
 1811.667,
 29530.172100000003,
 540402.1494300001,
 10970163.633429004,
 244634649.02546683,
 5944621971.318845,
 156343557845.68555,
 4424522687032.902,
 134063037417096.89,
 4330236108572230.5,
 1.4852709852402752e+17,
 5.391533676422196e+18,
 2.0649573980697022e+20,
 8.321778314220898e+21,
 3.5201122269154393e+23,
 1.5594097165235392e+25,
 7.220066987503985e+26,
 3.487292354964425e+28,
 1.7541080545471055e+30,
 inf,
 nan,
 nan]
```

Comment: `float` has a maximum value (though what exactly that value is will depend on your computer). You might be interested in the [`Decimal`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/decimal.html) class, which lets you determine its maximum size.

Comment: How do I know maximum size for decimal. Is there any specific code and is there a way to increase the maximum value of decimal. Please help me out